# Getting text between option tags to use with Google Maps route calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, tags

Here is the section of Javascript I am working on. It displays the correct address for each part of the route segment, but I would like to be able to also have it display the text in between the option tags in the html so that I can identify which address belongs to which person. I figured Jquery would be the best way to do that, but I could not figure out how to get it to display the text between the option tags that corresponded to the starting address of the particular leg of the route. Is there a way to do this using Jquery?

```
  var totalTime = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
  var routeSegment = i + 1;

  travelTime.push(route.legs[i].duration.value);
  travelDistance.push(route.legs[i].distance.value);
  summaryPanel.innerHTML += 'Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '<br>';
  var name = $("#waypoints option[value='route.legs[i]']").text()

  summaryPanel.innerHTML += name + '<br>';
  summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
  summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br><br>';
  summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br>';
  summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].duration.text + '<br>';
  summaryPanel.innerHTML += '_________________________________________________' + '<br><br>'; 
  }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="text"><b>Start:</b>

            <select id="start">
                <option value="100 Main Street, Hartford, CT">Office Location</option>
            </select>
            <br> <b>Waypoints:</b> 
            <br> <i>(Ctrl-Click for up to 8 selections)</i> 
            <br>
            <select multiple id="waypoints">
                <option value="32 Storrs Road, Storrs, CT">John Smith</option>
                <option value="32 Elm Street, Enfield, CT">Jane Doe</option>
                <option value="2100 Hillside Road, Storrs, CT">Jonathan</option>
            </select>
            <br> <b>End:</b>

            <select id="end">
                <option value="100 Main Street, Hartford, CT">Office Location</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();">
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="directions_panel"></div>
            <div id="total_time"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozhhqb1b/2/)

Comment: Sorry, didn't post the HTML for confidentiality reasons. Basically there is a list of client address as the value of each option, and the text between the tag is their name. I want it to show the name of the client as well as their address so that I don't have to go through the list and match it up manually.

Comment: Post sample data if you need to to make your question complete, preferably a [Minimal, **Complete**, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsargey/ozhhqb1b/1/) The map doesn't show up when you run it on JS Fiddle, but I'm assuming that's because it's using the Maps API. But all of the code is there. Sorry if it looks bad, it's one of the first programs I've written and some of the code was taken from the code samples on the Google Maps API website and I just changed it to fit my needs. I know it isn't very minimal, but I couldn't think of how to shrink it without taking out important things. Let me know if you need me to remove more code. Thanks for all your help @geocodezip

Comment: That's the file I put all of the JavaScript code in. I forgot to get rid of that line.

Comment: So if you selected John Smith and Jane Doe, is there a way to show their names in the output, in addition to their address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/branches/polys/geoxml3.js) to parse out the text content of an HTML element:

```
//nodeValue: Extract the text value of a DOM node, with leading and trailing whitespace trimmed
// from geoxml3: https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/branches/polys/geoxml3.js
function nodeValue(node, defVal) {
  var retStr="";
  if (!node) {
    return (typeof defVal === 'undefined' || defVal === null) ? '' : defVal;
  }
   if(node.nodeType==3||node.nodeType==4||node.nodeType==2){
      retStr+=node.nodeValue;
   }else if(node.nodeType==1||node.nodeType==9||node.nodeType==11){
      for(var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;++i){
         retStr+=arguments.callee(node.childNodes[i]);
      }
   }
   return retStr;
};
```

If I change your code to create an array of "names" associated with each waypoint using that function to populate the array with the text content of each selected option element:

```
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var waypts = [];
    var names = [];
    var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected == true) {
            waypts.push({
                location: checkboxArray[i].value,
                stopover: true
            });
            names.push(nodeValue(checkboxArray[i]));
        }
    }
    names.push("Office");
```

Then they can be put in the sidebar like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
   var routeSegment = i + 1;

   travelTime.push(route.legs[i].duration.value);
   travelDistance.push(route.legs[i].distance.value);
   var name = $("#waypoints option[value='route.legs[i]']").text();
   summaryPanel.innerHTML += 'Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '<br>';
   summaryPanel.innerHTML += 'to: ' + names[i] + '<br>';
   summaryPanel.innerHTML += name + '<br>';
   summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
   summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br><br>';
   summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br>';
   summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].duration.text + '<br>';
   summaryPanel.innerHTML += '_________________________________________________' + '<br><br>';
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozhhqb1b/4/)

working code snippet:

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var names = [];

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var connecticut = new google.maps.LatLng(41.6000, -72.7000);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: connecticut
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var waypts = [];
  var names = [];
  var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected == true) {
      waypts.push({
        location: checkboxArray[i].value,
        stopover: true
      });
      names.push(nodeValue(checkboxArray[i]));
    }
  }
  names.push("Office");
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };




  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
      var total = document.getElementById('total_time');
      total.innerHTML = '';
      var travelTime = [];
      var travelDistance = [];
      Array.prototype.sum = function() {
        for (var i = 0, L = this.length, sum = 0; i < L; sum += this[i++]);
        return sum;
      }


      // For each route, display summary information.
      var totalTime = 0
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;

        travelTime.push(route.legs[i].duration.value);
        travelDistance.push(route.legs[i].distance.value);
        var name = $("#waypoints option[value='route.legs[i]']").text();
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += 'Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '<br>';
        if (route.waypoint_order && (i < route.waypoint_order.length)) {
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += 'to: ' + names[route.waypoint_order[i]] + '<br>';
        } else {
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += 'to: ' + names[i] + '<br>';
        }
        if (route.waypoints_order && i < route.waypoints_order
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += name + '<br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br><br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].duration.text + '<br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '_________________________________________________' + '<br><br>';
      }




      secondsTotal = travelTime.sum();

      function fromSeconds(sec) {
        var d = new Date(0, 0, 0);
        d.setSeconds(+sec);
        if (secondsTotal < 7200) {
          return (d.getHours() ? d.getHours() + ' hour and ' : '') + d.getMinutes() + ' minutes';
        } else {
          return (d.getHours() ? d.getHours() + ' hours and ' : '') + d.getMinutes() + ' minutes';
        }
      }

      milesTotal = Math.round(travelDistance.sum() * 0.000621371);

      // change to mpg of car 
      var mpg = 22;
      // change to cost of gas
      var costOfGas = 2.79;
      var fuelCost = ((milesTotal / mpg) * costOfGas).toFixed(2);
      var fuelReimbursement = (milesTotal * .2).toFixed(2);
      var fuelRemainder = (fuelReimbursement - fuelCost).toFixed(2);



      total.innerHTML += fromSeconds(secondsTotal) + ' total' + '<br>';
      total.innerHTML += milesTotal + ' miles total' + '<br><br>';
      total.innerHTML += 'Fuel cost: ' + '$' + fuelCost + '<br>';
      total.innerHTML += 'State reimbursement: ' + '$' + fuelReimbursement + '<br>';
      total.innerHTML += 'Amount leftover: ' + '$' + fuelRemainder;


    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

//nodeValue: Extract the text value of a DOM node, with leading and trailing whitespace trimmed
// from geoxml3: https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/branches/polys/geoxml3.js
function nodeValue(node, defVal) {
  var retStr = "";
  if (!node) {
    return (typeof defVal === 'undefined' || defVal === null) ? '' : defVal;
  }
  if (node.nodeType == 3 || node.nodeType == 4 || node.nodeType == 2) {
    retStr += node.nodeValue;
  } else if (node.nodeType == 1 || node.nodeType == 9 || node.nodeType == 11) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
      retStr += arguments.callee(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
  return retStr;
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#map-canvas {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  border-width: 2px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: "Arial", san-serif;
}
#waypoints {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#directions_panel,
#total_time {
  font-family: "Arial", san-serif;
  background-color: #FFFFFF
}
#total_time {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#text {
  margin: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="text"><b>Start:</b>

    <select id="start">
      <option value="100 Main Street, Hartford, CT">Office Location</option>
    </select>
    <br> <b>Waypoints:</b> 
    <br> <i>(Ctrl-Click for up to 8 selections)</i> 
    <br>
    <select multiple id="waypoints">
      <option value="32 Storrs Road, Storrs, CT">John Smith</option>
      <option value="32 Elm Street, Enfield, CT">Jane Doe</option>
      <option value="2100 Hillside Road, Storrs, CT">Jonathan</option>
    </select>
    <br> <b>End:</b>

    <select id="end">
      <option value="100 Main Street, Hartford, CT">Office Location</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="directions_panel"></div>
    <div id="total_time"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I didn't realize the fix would be so simple, but I never would have known where to look as all of my searches for an answer didn't seem to be pointing me in the right direction. Thanks again! :)

Comment: It may be simple, but without an example it would have been really hard to explain (I've tried before).

Comment: Actually, I have one more question. Is there a way to make it so that the names correspond to the address? It's just listing them in the order they appear, rather than matching it up to the address the name belongs to. @geocodezip

Comment: Sure.  Hadn't noticed the optimize_waypoints option was used.  Updated the code in my answer to handle that (use the waypoint_order array in the returned result).